# How do I create an app ID for like and send buttons from my website

Tags: facebook

I've been wrestling with Facebook xfbml code and og tags to insert a Like and Send button on pages of my website - and have decided that I really need an app ID as I'm getting errors from the send button - and also anticipate many thousands of pages being liked - and would like to manage them in an organised fashion, which I believe I can do if the website is registered as an app.

OK, so I started the process of creating my app - I got stuck almost straight away - on the basic info screen. None of the Tabs seem to fit my situation - I don't want my site to have a facebook login (I think... if that means that anyone who goes to it needs to first log in with Facebook) and it's not purely a mobile site etc... it's just a basic website that I need to Like and Send buttons to function on.

So I filled out the info that I can - noting the absence of the 'Website' tab that my 'How to' tutorial (non-FB) tells me should be there (perhaps that tab's been replaced with 'Website with Facebook login'?) and I try to continue but get this error:

You have specified an App Domains but have not specified a Site URL or a Mobile Web URL
www.mydomain.com.au must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web URL.

Can someone please illuminate me here?

Comment: „You have specified an App Domains but have not specified a Site URL or a Mobile Web URL www.mydomain.com.au must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web URL.” - that message is pretty self-explainatory, isn’t it? If you put in a value for app domain, you also have to put a corresponding website address into at least one of the fields ‚Website with Facebook Login’ or ‚Mobile Web URL’.

Comment: ok thanks... your answer highlights the true source of my hesitation. I don't understand what website with facebook login practically means. Does it mean everyone has to login with facebook to access my site... or that if they're not logged in and they like or send from my site, they are prompted to login in first?

Comment: No, it just means that you _can_ prompt users to login into facebook from your site – but you don’t **need** to, if your apps don’t require that.